# Javascript get query string parameter values that has query string parameter in turn

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I am pretty poor in regex so hoping to get some help here. 
I have an url which has a query string parameters. The parameter in turn is a url which has qs parameters of itself. 
For eg: my url is something like

> http://myurl.com/somepage?ref=/en-us/products-overview/find-product/home/kitchen/2980?source=google&isadvertisement=false&organic=true

Now when i use any of the functions to extract the whole query string parameter, i somehow get only the first one.

**What i am expecting is:** : */en-us/products-overview/find-product/home/kitchen/2980?source=google&isadvertisement=false&organic=true*

**But what i get is:** */en-us/products-overview/find-product/home/kitchen/2980?source=google*

notice that the other two parameters (isadvertisement and organic) are missing.

my function is

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    var url = 'http://myurl.com/somepage?ref=/en-us/products-overview/find-product/home/kitchen/2980?source=google&isadvertisement=false&organic=true';
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dLvnaec/1/):

i tried other links from SO to extract QS parameters. none of them seem to handle this scenario

Comment: Are there other parameters that may be included other than `ref`?

Comment: There could be..  not that we add it.. but there is a possibility..

Comment: a possible solution: **(new URL(url)).search.substr(5)**

Comment: The easiest fix would be to encode your `ref` value. Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/vwcj7dx6/ - This will also address any confusion if/when you decide to add additional parameters.

Comment: @Jack beautiful and simple solution. If you could write it as an answer, i will mark it..  thanks a lot. all this while, i was trying to fix the regex but you fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The ampersands in your url are being treated as top level parameter separators. If they are part of a parameter themselves, they need to be escaped. Your escaped url would look like http://myurl.com/somepage?ref=%2Fen-us%2Fproducts-overview%2Ffind-product%2Fhome%2Fkitchen%2F2980%3Fsource%3Dgoogle%26isadvertisement%3Dfalse%26organic%3Dtrue. How you encode the url depends on where it is coming from. JS provides the `encodeURIComponent()` function.

Then you could use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode that back to the expected url. The issue is coming from having nested query parameters.

To get query parameters in general though, a built in solution using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) could be something like:

```
var url=new URL('...');
for (var e of url.searchParams.entries()){
    console.log(e);
}
```